# Video uploader using angular 2 with typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, file-upload, video-processing

I want to make video uploader in my angular 2 with typescript project. As video size will be bigger, we want to cut down main file to multiple files and push with queue to server side API. As single file fails it just need to post small file only. On server side in C# API, I will merge all files and store main video file. Any plug-in available for such functionality in angular 2? or any idea about code of angular 2 to cut down video files? Don't want to use jQuery if possible.

Comment: Did you find how to make a video uploader in your angular 2 with typescript? I'm also trying to do the same

Comment: Used simple file uploader. Couldn't find anything for dividing into chunks and uploading them.

Comment: But did you manage to use the Youtube Data API to upload videos? I'm interested in knowing how you did you do it, I'm trying to the same except for the part of dividing them into chunks, I don't need to cut down the video. I would really appreciate if you can share the use of the uploader with angular and typescript

Comment: Not youtube APi. I just want to upload my file to my server's C# api.

html code

`<input type="file" class="form-control" name="documents" (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="files" multiple="multiple">`

   not sure it will help you or not.

Comment: `onChange(event: any) {
        let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
        if (fileList.length > 0) {
            let file: File = fileList[0];

            let formData: FormData = new FormData();

            formData.append(file.name, file);
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
            headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            //post formdata to server with httpcall
        }
    }`

Comment: I have same question. but in angular 8. I'm begginer :)